# TypeORM - Getting objects of provided id, which is one relation away

Tags: api, nestjs, typeorm

I want to get objects from table providing id, which is in relation with table, which is in another relation. It looks like this:

Hand is in relation manyToOne with Action (hand can have only one action),
Action is in relation manyToOne with Situation (action can have only one situation)

I'm trying to make GET request for hands in which I'm providing situationId.

Simplified entities:

```
@Entity()
export class Hand {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  hand_id: number;

  @Column()
  hand: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => Action, action => action.simplifiedhands, { eager: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
  action: Action;
}


@Entity()
export class Action {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    action_id: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => Situation, situation => situation.actions, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn({name: 'situation'})
    situation: Situation;

    @OneToMany(type => Hand, hand => hand.action)
    hands: Hand[];

    @OneToMany(type => Hand, hand => hand.action)
    hands: Hand[];
}


@Entity()
export class Situation {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  situation_id: number;

  @ManyToOne(type => Strategy, strategy => strategy.situations, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
  strategy: Strategy;

  @OneToMany(type => Action, action => action.situation)
  actions: Action[];
}
```

What approaches didn't work for me so far (just example variants):

```
return await this.handsRepository.find({
      relations: ["action", "action.situation"],
      where: {
        "situation": id
      }
    });
```

and

```
return await this.handsRepository.find({
      join: {
        alias: "hands",
        leftJoinAndSelect: {
          "action": "hand.action",
          "situation": "action.situation"
        }
      },
      where: {
        "situation": id
      }
    });
```

Generally both 'works' but provide all the records, like there were no where condition.

Comment: Can you please attach the entities code?

Comment: Oh yeah sure, added

Comment: Did the answer below helped you solve the issue?

Comment: I did it the other way. I'm getting situation object with array of actions containing arrays of hands.

Answer (score 0):

The keys in the object you assign to `where` should be members of the entity of the repository, in your case `Hand`, since `situation` is a member of action it's not working. I'm surprised you didn't mention any errors.

You can do one of the following (example for postgres)

Using query builder:

```
return await this.handsRepository.createQueryBuilder(Hand, 'hand')
            .leftJoin('hand.action', 'action')
            .leftJoin('action.situation', 'situation')
            .where('situation.id = :id', { id })
            .getMany();
```

Or, you can try the following (success is not guaranteed):

```
return await this.handsRepository.find({
      relations: ["action", "action.situation"],
      where: {
        action: {
            situation: { id }
        }
      }
    });
```